# Support of a module over polynomials: intuitive meaning

Tags: abstract-algebra, modules

I find myself working with modules over complex polynomials in more variables, say $C[u_1,\dots,u_l]$. One can introduce the concept of *support* of the module $H$ as
\begin{equation}
supp H = \cap_{f:fH=0} V_f
\end{equation}
with $V_f\subset \mathbb C^l$ the set of points $u\in \mathbb C^l$ such that $f(u)=0$.
Now: what's the intuitive idea behind the support? Does it have anyhting to do with the support of a function, conceptually speaking?

For example, when the module is free the support is the whole space. Now say $H=C[u_1,u_2]/(u_1-u_2)$, then the support is the line $u_1=u_2$; I would be tempted to say, in a complete uninformal way, that if we restrict the domain of the polynomials from $C^2$ to $supp H$, then the module is free. Can this be formalized, in any sense? Is then the support a subset of the domain making the module free, in some sense?

Follow-up question. Suppose that I pick $H=C[u]/(u-2)\otimes C[u]/(u-3)$. Then the support is the empty set. What would this *mean*?

Comment: For the last part, it means that a number can't be both $2$ and $3$.

Comment: well, yes, that's already something. I was actually wondering whether I could get some info about the module

Comment: Ah yes, then the module is zero, because $H = \mathbb{C}[u]/(u-2,u-3)$ and $(u-2,u-3) = (1)$.

Comment: ah-ha. Ok, computations confim. Thanks. Do you have a favourite way of thinking of the support?
I mean, the fact that the module is zero if the support is empty would seem to confirm that this notion is cousin of the analogous notion for functions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My way of thinking about support of modules is in the context of schemes (but you don't need the full generality to get something out of it).

Basically, if $R$ is a commutative ring, then you think of $Spec(R)$ as a geometric space whose ring of regular functions is $R$. Then any $R$-module $M$ gives a sheaf of modules $\widetilde{M}$ over $Spec(R)$.

In a simpler language it means that when you localize $R$, you can also localize $M$ ($S^{-1}M$ is a $S^{-1}R$-module), so you can think of $M$ as local data that glue together.

In particular, if $\mathfrak{p}$ is a prime ideal (ie a point of $Spec(R)$), then you can localize at this point : $M_\mathfrak{p}$ is a $R_\mathfrak{p}$-module. In the case $R = \mathbb{C}[x_1,\dots,x_n]$ this has a strong geometric intuition : if $\mathfrak{p}$ is a maximal ideal, then it canonically corresponds to a point $a=(a_1,\dots,a_n)\in \mathbb{C}^n$ and $R_\mathfrak{p}$ is the ring of germs of regular functions at $a$.

Now the support of $M$ is the set of $\mathfrak{p}$ such that $M_\mathfrak{p}\neq 0$. So it's the set of points at which $M$ is non-zero. If you think of elements of $M$ as functions, you can interpret $M(\mathfrak{p}) = M_\mathfrak{p}/\mathfrak{p}M_\mathfrak{p}$ as the vector space (over $k(\mathfrak{p}) = R_\mathfrak{p}/\mathfrak{p}R_\mathfrak{p}$, which in your case is just $\mathbb{C}$) of values at $\mathfrak{p}$, and the natural function $M\to M_\mathfrak{p}\to M(\mathfrak{p})$ as the evaluation map. Then the support would be the set of points over which there is at least one function in $M$ that doesn't vanish.

Your definition amounts to considering only maximal ideals of $R = \mathbb{C}[x_1,\dots,x_n]$ instead of prime ideals, which is a reasonable first approximation of the finer notion I used here (considering prime ideals allows you to localize not only at points of $\mathbb{C}^n$ but also at irreducible subvarieties).

Note that the examples you put in your question are all of the form $R/I$ for an ideal $I$. In this case the support is just $V(I)$, the variety defined by $I$, and $R/I$ is the ring of regular functions on $V(I)$. But this is really a special case because in this case your module has a natural algebra structure.

Comment: yikes, so much algebra. It will take a while to be able to digest this answer - but thanks, I'll keep meditating in the next days.

Comment: in case you're still there: how am I supposed to regard elements of M as functions? I mean, per se they don't have any such structure, in general

Comment: That's what I tried to explain with the $M(\mathfrak{p})$, but it's just a sort of intuition. For each $a\in \mathbb{C}^n$ you get a $\mathbb{C}$-vector space that we can call $M(a)$, and there is a natural map $M\to M(a)$ which we can see as an evaluation map. So for any $f\in M$ we can write $f(a)$ the image of $f$ in $M(a)$ and think of it as the "value" of $f$ at $a$ (but the set of values varies with the point, so it's not *really* a function). In the case $M = \mathbb{C}[x_1,\dots,x_n]$, $M(a)=\mathbb{C}$ for all $a$, and $f(a)$ is the usual value of the polynomial $f$ at $a$.